# Can Hibernate generate DDL column names that match java property names verbatim?

Tags: java, json, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am building a JDBC<->JSON utility class and running into discrepancies with hibernate generated DDL columns not matching my object property names.  I tried writing a custom PhysicalNamingStrategy to quote the Identifier returned from toPhysicalColumnName and that only raised exceptions downstream in the foreign key generation.  My database supports mixed case column names so JSON serialization should be a piece of cake!

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is using field name for column name by default. You can change default field <-> column mapping by using `@Column(name = "column_name")` on field.